# even odd sort behavior on a GPU using a kernel of one thread with sequential implementation

Tags: linux, sorting, cuda

```
__global__ void sort_single(int *size , int *arr){
for ( int m = 0; m < *size / 2; m++)
{
    for (int  i = 0; i < *size; i += 2)
    {
        if (arr[i + 1] > arr[i])
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    /*for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");*/
    for ( int i = 1; i < *size; i += 2)
    {
        if (arr[i + 1] > arr[i])
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

This is a kernel code for CUDA GPUs .It does a an even odd sort .
In order to call it I use this from main after preparing all the data.
`sort_single<<<1,1>>>(d_a,d_b);`

My question is that why does it give incorrect results here whereas if I run this code as a regular C/C++ function code it gives correct result .If I remove the outer loop in the kernel and call the kernel in that loop it works correctly as below.

```
for ( int m = 0; m < N / 2; m++)
sort_single<<<1,1>>>(d_a,d_b);
```

I am doing the same thing here 
I think it has to do something with the number of steps this algorithm requires for example it needs 2 steps for every iteration .

1. comparing the even index with the next one.
2. comparing the odd index with the next one.

I am unable to understand why this happens as you increase the number of elements in the array since I am using single GPU thread . I need clarity on how the GPU single thread is different than the CPU in order to understand the current behaviour.
[the whole single file link on drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15KW9nkYOnRdIKO1fQVO8xris3KdHgm3t/view?usp=sharing)

Here are the file contents:

```
#include "stdio.h"
__global__ void add(int *a , int *b ,int*c){

        c[blockIdx.x] = a[blockIdx.x] + b[blockIdx.x];

}
__global__ void sort_single(int *size , int *arr){

    for ( int m = 0; m < *size / 2; m++)
    {   
        for (int  i = 0; i < *size; i += 2)
        {
            if (arr[i + 1] > arr[i])
            {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;

            }
        }
        /*for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");*/
        for ( int i = 1; i < *size; i += 2)
        {
            if (arr[i + 1] > arr[i])
            {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;

            }
        }

    }

}
void random_ints(int *a, int N)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    a[i] = rand() %5000;
}
void uniform_ints(int *a, int N)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    a[i] = i+1;

}

int main(int argc , char**argv){
    int N = 8;
    if(argc>1)
      {
          N=atoi(argv[1]);
      }
    int *a , *b  ;
    int *d_a , *d_b ;
    int isize = N * sizeof(int);

    a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));a[0] = N;
    b = (int *)malloc(isize);uniform_ints(b , N);


    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a,sizeof(int));

    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b,isize);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
        goto Error;
    }    

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_a, a , sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_b, b , isize,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }

    sort_single<<<1,1>>>(d_a,d_b);
    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }

    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(b, d_b , isize,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
        goto Error;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    printf("\n");
    Error:
    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    return cudaStatus;
}
```

Comment: Please edit a proper [MCVE] into your question. It is very hard or impossible to say what might be wrong with out on.

Comment: amongst possibly other problems, your code will make an illegal, out-of-bounds access at this line (in the odd, i.e. 2nd sweep, if the overall size is even): `if (arr[i + 1] > arr[i])`.  Run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.  Since the for-loop goes up to `*size`, `[i+1]` will index out-of-bounds.  This is simply broken code, and is not unique to a CPU or GPU implementation.

Comment: @ talonmies The other code is actually a compilable code of the file which you can download and compile using nvcc .I don't know why its showing contents and I don't know how to turn off them .

Comment: @RobertCrovella Sorry I didnt mention it but I am currently only doing this for even number of elements in array.

Comment: with an even number of elements in the array, the odd sweep will still be called, and it will still generate an out-of-bounds access.  Run the code with `cuda-memcheck`

Comment: @RobertCrovella sorry it only works on sm3 I have sm21

Comment: @Sam: This isn't how things work around here. Everything you need must be posted *in the question*. This exists for other people's benefit, not just yours. Unless you can guarantee that what is at the end of the link will be accessible forever, it is unacceptable to post that link rather than include code in your question. And then there is the problem that the type of link you have posted is the #1 vector for targeted malware delivery, and I for one can't (and  won't) access that via my professional internet access

Comment: `cuda-memcheck` works on sm21

Comment: but I get a device not supported error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code compiles in simple C/C++ function as well as cuda kernel since it is based on assumption that size of array is even. It gives correct result the mistake was mallocking. Anyways thanks for the response.